# Difficulty converting date in format yyyy-mm-dd to textual date format like Monday 21 Jan 2012 PHP

Tags: strtotime, mktime, php

I am trying to convert a date in format `(yyyy-mm-dd)` to a textual date format like `Monday 21 Jan 2012` using PHP. I have tried using `mktime()` function but I'm a novice and I cant figure it out. 
Any help will be grealty appreciated.

e.g :-   `convert 2012-04-27 => Friday 27 April 2012` 

Thanks.

Comment: This is what you need: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class (which is recommended over `strtotime`):

```
$date = new DateTime($date_string);
$textual = $date->format("l j M Y");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I got this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("l j M Y", strtotime('2012-04-26'));
```